# How to switch between languages?

Tags: 11.04, gnome

I didn't like Unity and installed Gnome-shell on my Ubuntu 11.04 and everything was alright. Except that I can't switch my keyboard between languages!

How can I fix this? What's wrong? I don't have this problem in Unity or Classic Ubuntu but in Gnome-shell, It just doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> to switch between different keyboard layouts. Usually, that would let you change between different languages.

If you want to configure the keyboard shortcut, search for "Keyboard Input Methods" in the gnome-shell overview and open it. Then, change the keyboard shortcuts there.

[image]